# Yii2 - API Rest - ActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-api

I am building a REST API using Yii2 Basic Template. I am getting an error:

```
exception 'yii\base\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Response content must be a string or an object implementing __toString().' in /Users/aurasix/ASX-Startups/ASX-CMS/asx-api-yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:1062

Copy Stacktrace Search Stackoverflow Search Google Exception
Invalid Argument – yii\base\InvalidArgumentException
Response content must be a string or an object implementing __toString().
```

I am following the guide on yii2 website: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-resources

Trying to use collections, in order to use pagination and ordering in the future, am I missing something?

I understand that if I use ActiveController probably this will be easier but I want to understand the full process that is why I am using Controller. Also I want full control, I think ActiveController will publish all methods just by defining the model, right?

My controller I am not extending it from ActiveController but from Controller

```
namespace app\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use app\modules\v1\models\Blog;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

class BlogController extends Controller {

    public $serializer = [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
        'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
    ];

    public function actionIndex() {
        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Blog::find()
        ]);
    }

}
```

My model:

```
namespace app\modules\v1\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\Linkable;

class Blog extends ActiveRecord implements Linkable {

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'blog_post';
    }

    public function fields() {
        return [
            'id',
            'slug',
            'title',
            'full_content'
        ];
    }

    public function extraFields() {
        return [
            'publish_date',
            'short_content'
        ];
    }

    public function getLinks() {
        return [

        ];
    }

}
```

In config.php

```
'response' => [
            'formatters' => [
                \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter',
                    'prettyPrint' => YII_DEBUG, // use "pretty" output in debug mode
                    'encodeOptions' => JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE,
                ],
            ],
        ],
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => 'v1/blog',
                    'pluralize'=>false
                ]
            ],
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use [`yii\rest\Controller`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-controller#$serializer-detail) as a base controller class. It will not do all the magic for you like `yii\rest\ActiveController` do, but it contains some basic request filtering and response formatting features.

`yii\web\Controller` does not contain `$serializer` property, it will not serialize your action response, so you cannot return `ActiveDataProvider` in action method. 
You should look to [`yii\rest\Controller` source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/abeb3b1a371a3b0babe3fae2d7d6a36765b03bc0/framework/rest/Controller.php) - it uses `afterAction()` to serialize `ActiveDataProvider` returned from action. Without it you cannot configure serializer via `$serializer` property or return `ActiveDataProvider` in action method.

Answer (score 1):

Yii REST Services Provide you mainly 2 types of controllers that are

- `yii\rest\ActiveController`
- `yii\rest\Controller`

You need to extend your controller from the `yii\rest\Controller` not `yii\web\Controller` as there is no property with the name `$serializer` for [**`yii\web\Controller`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller) that you are trying to specify but for [**`yii\rest\Controller`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-controller#$serializer-detail)